# pytorch: how can I use picture as label in dataloader?

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

I want to do some image reconstruction using autoencoders in pytorch, however, I didn't find a way to use image as label for an input image.(the label image is different from original ones)

I've tried the image folder method, but I think that's for classfication and I am currently unable to come up with one solution. Should I create a custom dataset for this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your custom `Dataset`, below is a simple example.

```py
import torch.utils.data.Dataset as Dataset

class CustomDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, input_imgs, label_imgs, transform):

        self.input_imgs = input_imgs
        self.label_imgs = label_imgs
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.input_imgs)


    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_img, label_img = self.input_imgs[idx], self.label_imgs[idx]
        return self.transform(input_img), self.transform(label_img)
```

And then, pass it to Dataloader:

```py
dataloader = DataLoader(CustomDataset)
```

Comment: I wonder if my data is orgnized as train/input/001.png...002.png train/label/001.png, how should I use the above code?

Comment: I‘ve upvoted, but my reputation is below 15, so it will not display publicly.